# Get selected date from wpf datepicker control in winforms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, datepicker

I have a c# window application using a datepicker control from wpf.Embedding. I have been successful in adding it to the winform application, but I am unable to get the value from the control into my application variable.
I tried selecteddate property on button click in winform but it returns a null value.

Answer (score 0):

The `SelectedDate` property is what you need.  The value will be `null` until you've actually chosen a date.

Comment: value property is not available. I have Integrated wpf datepicker in my window form

Comment: even when selecting a date it is shown as null. I have Integrated wpf datepicker in my window form using the element host tool from wpf interoperability